# Ant <apply> in multiple directories

Tags: ant

I want to simplify this:

```
<target name="build">
   <parallel>
      <antcall target="build-A" />
      <antcall target="build-B" />
      <antcall target="build-C" />
   </parallel>
</target>

<target name="build-A">
   <exec executable="tool.exe" dir="projects/A">
      <arg value="input.xml" />
   </exec>
</target>
```

where `build-B` and `build-C` do the exact same thing (only in dirs `B` and `C`, respectively), into something akin to this:

```
<dirset id="projects" dir="." >
   <include name="projects/*" />
</dirset>

<apply executable="tool.exe" parallel="true">
   <arg value="input.xml" />
   <dirset refid="projects" />
</apply>
```

This doesn't work because `apply` will do one of the following:

If `parallel` is set to `true`,

```
tool.exe input.xml projects/A projects/B projects/C
```

or if `parallel` is set to `false`,

```
tool.exe projects/A/input.xml
...waits for tool.exe to complete...
tool.exe projects/B/input.xml
...etc
```

And even that is incorrect because `tool.exe` expects to be run *within* the `projects/A` directory.

Is there a way to parallelize this such that the output I get is equivalent to:

```
cd project/A
tool.exe input.xml

cd ../B
tool.exe input.xml

cd ../C
tool.exe input.xml
```

but in parallel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use [ant-contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/index.html)'s [for task](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/for.html) to do this.

```
<for param="dir" parallel="true">
    <dirset id="projects" dir="." >
        <include name="projects/*" />
    </dirset>
    <sequential>
        <exec executable="tool.exe" dir="@{dir}">
            <arg value="input.xml" />
        </exec>
    </sequential>
</for>
```

Comment: I had *just* discovered this, and came to write my own answer. :) You win the upvote.